# Find the valid integer m, n for the formula: $0<50(m^2-n^3)^2<n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I encountered this special inequation several days ago and wanted to solve it by programming. But the result seems to be too big for a laptop to calculate. Meanwhile, I thought there might be some papers related to similar questions out there but I don't know how to search it. I suppose it may relate to the number theory and give a tag of it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to find counter-examples of the [Hall's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_conjecture) for $C=\frac{1}{\sqrt{50}}$, while the wikipedia page gives a solution for $C\sim 1/50$ and the example is $$447884928428402042307918^2 - 5853886516781223^3 = -1641843$$ and $$50*1641843^2=134782421832450<5853886516781223$$

Comment: (Or maybe he saw this conjecture and misread it and actually he is trying to ask for a solution with 50 replaced by 2500 which is unknown so far? That's my conjecture on this question. ㋡)